# How to fill in a dataframe piecemeal in Python

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have a dataframe Results with columns ID and Prediction, and a subfunction Calc that returns a dataframe of ID, pred for some subset of the IDs at a time. I would like to fill in Results as predictions come in. In R, this would be simply:

```
for x in cycles
    temp = Calc(x)
    Results[temp, on="ID",Prediction:=pred]
```

How do I do this in Python? When I try using merge with something like `Results = Results.merge(temp, on=['ID'], how='left')` it tries to fill the whole column, so in the second loop I end up with Results having columns ID, Prediction_x, Prediction_y. One solution might be to make a new table and append temp in each cycle, then merge at the end, but I feel like there has to be a better way...

EDIT: Full worked example using not_speshal's solution:

```
Results = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1,2,3,4]})
Results["Prediction"] = np.nan
Results = Results.set_index("ID")
def Calc(x):
  if x == 1:
    return pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1,2], 'Prediction': [5,6]})
  if x == 2:
    return pd.DataFrame({'ID': [3,4], 'Prediction': [7,8]})

cycles = [1,2]
for x in cycles:
  temp = Calc(x)
  Results = Results.fillna(temp.set_index("ID"))

### Results Output ###
    Prediction
ID  
1   5.0
2   6.0
3   7.0
4   8.0
```

Comment: `Results.set_index("ID").fillna(temp.set_index("ID"))`

Comment: I'm not really following the description, and I don't know R. Could you make a [mre]? For specifics see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341). I'd want to see some input data (`Results` and `temp`), desired output, and current output.

Comment: not_speshal's solution works for me but I'll add it as a full example for anyone who comes across this post in the future

Comment: @Sinnombre Don't put a solution in the question; post an answer instead. (Yes, you can [answer your own question](/help/self-answer).) And please still make a [mre] so that the question itself is more useful. IMO, understanding the problem is just as important as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Full example using not_speshal's solution:

```
Results = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1,2,3,4]})
Results["Prediction"] = np.nan
Results = Results.set_index("ID")
def Calc(x):
  if x == 1:
    return pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1,2], 'Prediction': [5,6]})
  if x == 2:
    return pd.DataFrame({'ID': [3,4], 'Prediction': [7,8]})

cycles = [1,2]
for x in cycles:
  temp = Calc(x)
  Results = Results.fillna(temp.set_index("ID"))

### Results Output ###
    Prediction
ID  
1   5.0
2   6.0
3   7.0
4   8.0
```